# I am getting Error (1064) with this

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to make tables from a lua script (on a fiveM server) however I get the 1064 error when it tries to run the lines below. I don't know where the problem lies. I will post some of the lines as they are all similar. I am running the latest version of mysql database.

```
ALTER TABLE vrp_user_vehicles ADD IF NOT EXISTS veh_type varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default' ;

ALTER TABLE vrp_user_vehicles ADD IF NOT EXISTS vehicle_plate varchar(255) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE vrp_user_vehicles ADD IF NOT EXISTS vehicle_colorprimary varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;

ALTER TABLE vrp_user_vehicles ADD IF NOT EXISTS vehicle_turbo varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'off';
```

Comment: AFAIK `if not exists` sentence is not supported in that context

Comment: Please, *please*, [edit] your question so it shows the complete error message. Otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the mysql manual on [alter table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) statement, you can see that it does not support `IF NOT EXISTS` clause. You need to remove them from your statements.

You must use the [columns view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) in the `information_schema` if you want to check if a field exists.

```
select count(*) from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='your db name' and table_name='vrp_user_vehicles' and column_name='veh_type'
```